# Javascript: Sorting Parsed JSON within _.each loop

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, sorting

`var Bible = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(bible.json, 'utf8') );
_.each(Bible, function (b, Book) {
  return Book;
});`

This outputs each book name from the Bible (ex. Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, etc.). The problem is that the books from the JSON file are not in order. I have tried to sort them in various ways, but nothing seems possible inside of the _.each loop. When I did this:

`correctlyOrderedList.indexOf(Book) - correctlyOrderedList.indexOf(b);`

It returned the index of each one correctly, but I still can't sort those within the ).each loop as far as I am aware. Is there a way to order it prior to the _.each loop or is there a way to sort it within?

Comment: Try `_.each(_.sort(Bible), function(..) {...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort inside `each` because that would be too late.
But you can sort before using `_.each`:

```
var Bible = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(bible.json, 'utf8') );
Bible.sort(); // sorts in place
_.each(Bible, function (b, Book) { 
  return Book; 
});
```

Or pass the sorted value as a parameter to `each`:

```
var Bible = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(bible.json, 'utf8') );
_.each(Bible.sort(), function (b, Book) { 
  return Book; 
});
```

Comment: This worked. In my case, I had to deal with the Bible variable a little differently because it was an object. After passing it through a couple for loops, I was able to produce a sortable array from the original object.
  
```var index = [];
          var correctOrder = canon.OT + canon.NT;
          for (book in Bible) {index.push([book]);};
          for (var b=0, book, bible=[]; book=index[b]; ++b) {bible.push(book[0]);};
          bible.sort(function(a, b) {return correctOrder.indexOf(a) - correctOrder.indexOf(b);});```

Sorted & ready to go: `_.each(bible, function (Book) {return Book});`

Comment: This is likely messier than it needs to be, but it was the best I could come up with so far. I'm trying to make it less spaghettified. Your answer was definitely what I needed though, I just had to figure out how to convert the object into an array (I think that's what I did?).

Comment: After consulting a few other stack overflow answers, I discovered that underscore has a way to put keys into an array! This would have been huge to have understood a long time ago, but I suppose that's part of learning. Here's my cleaned up version:
  
`_.keys(Bible).sort(function(a, b) {return correctOrder.indexOf(a) - correctOrder.indexOf(b);}); bible.forEach(function getBooks(Book) {return Book});`