# ES6 : sorting an array based on another array order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

```
sortedArray = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
unSortedArray = [{id: 8, text : 'abcd'}, {id: 4, text : 'ab'}, {id: 1, text : 'cd'}, {id: 2, text : 'def'}, {id: 3, text : 'abcd'}, {id: 5, text : 'abcd'}]
```

I want to sort `unSortedArray` based on items of `sortedArray` and want only object which has same id as in `sortedArray`

**Result expected**

```
[{id: 1, text : 'cd'}, {id: 2, text : 'def'}, {id: 3, text : 'abcd'}, {id: 4, text : 'abc'}]
```

I have tried similar suggestions based on similar questions.
Adding link of such question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377495/sort-an-array-in-the-same-order-of-another-array)

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let sortedArray = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }];
let unSortedArray = [
 { id: 8, text: "abcd" },
 { id: 4, text: "ab" },
 { id: 1, text: "cd" },
 { id: 2, text: "def" },
 { id: 3, text: "abcd" },
 { id: 5, text: "abcd" }
];

// Method 1 - Reduce
let sorted = sortedArray
 .map(itm => itm.id)
 .reduce((acc, id) => acc.concat(unSortedArray.filter(itm => itm.id === id)), []);

console.log(sorted);

// Method 2 - Map + flat
sorted = sortedArray
        .map(a => unSortedArray.filter(b => b.id === a.id))
        .flat();
;

console.log(sorted);


// Method 3 - flatMap
sorted = sortedArray
        .flatMap(a => unSortedArray.filter(b => b.id === a.id))
;

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: I'd make it even simpler and use `.map` from `sortedArray` to entries in `unSortedArray`. No real need for `reduce` here.

Comment: You are right – I've updated the snippet (including flat)

Comment: If mapping one to many, you can just use `.flatMap`. But if it's just 1:1 mapping them `a.map(x => b.find(y => <equality between x and y>))` suffices.

Comment: It all boils down to browser support :)

Comment: I don't think a browser that supports `flat` will not support `flatMap` or vice versa.

Comment: It seems you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get a hash table first and then map only wanted items.

```js
var sortedArray = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
    unSortedArray = [{ id: 8, text : 'abcd' }, { id: 4, text : 'ab' }, { id: 1, text : 'cd' }, { id: 2, text : 'def' }, { id: 3, text : 'abcd' }, { id: 5, text : 'abcd' }],
    items = unSortedArray.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.id] = o, r), {}),
    result = sortedArray.map(({ id }) => items[id]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```